# Suppress factory_boy captured logging information?

Tags: django, factory-boy

Is there any way to suppress (i.e. hide) the captured logging information block factory boy generates when a test fails or generates an error?  I'm talking about this:

```
SomeError: you encountered an error
----------- >> begin captured loggin << -----------
... DEBUG information
----------- >> end captured loggin << -------------

---------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test...
```

Often times, this information isn't relevant or necessary to solve the problem and it's just a lot of stuff I have to scroll up past to see what caused the error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can change the factory_boy logging level with:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("factory").setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

Replacing `WARN` with whatever level you want. I don't know where to put this in a Django environment, but you can put this in your test file or some global initializer.

This should suppress any logging except actual factory_boy errors & warnings.

Weird default, since factory_boy debugging is rarely helpful and is incredibly verbose.

Comment: Thanks Jim!  It worked like a charm.  This will save me miles of scrolling.